# Need to Execute Function before render() in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a login system with React which stores a session when the user logs in. When the page is reloaded, I have added a function which should check if the session exists and then either `setState()` to `true` or to `false`.

As I'm new to React, I'm not sure how to execute this function. Please see my code below for **App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            renderLoginForm: true
        };
        this.handleLoginFormMount = this.handleLoginFormMount.bind(this);
    }

    handleLoginFormMount() {
        this.setState({
            renderLoginForm: false
        });
    }

    // Check session function.
    checkSession() {
        fetch('/check-session', {
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((sessionResult) => {
            if (sessionResult.username) {
                console.log('false');
                this.setState({
                    renderLoginForm: false
                });
            } else {
                console.log('true');
                this.setState({
                    renderLoginForm: true
                });
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        });
    }

    render() {

        checkSession();

        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.renderLoginForm ? <LoginForm mountLoginForm={this.handleLoginFormMount} /> : null}
                {this.state.renderLoginForm ? null : <Dashboard />}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Having `checkSession()` in this position outputs the following in the console when loading the page:

`Line 50:  'checkSession' is not defined  no-undef`

If I put the function outside of the `class App extends React.Component {}`, then it tells me that I cannot set the state of undefined.

Comment: First of all as  checkSession is component function , u need to use this.checkSession(); to call it. For checking whether the user sesssion is valid or not. You make the api call in lefecycle methods. I cannot tell you correct lifecycle before i know what version of reactjs you are using. Please tell that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the latest version of React.

Comment: Side note: Your `fetch` call is missing a check for success, details in [this post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Having `checkSession()` in this position outputs the following in the console when loading the page:
>
> ```
> Line 50:  'checkSession' is not defined  no-undef
> ```

That's because it's a method, but you're calling it like a freestanding function. The call should be `this.checkSession();`. But keep reading.

Separately:

The `render` function must be pure, it cannot have side-effects like changing state. Instead, put any side-effects code in [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount); from the documentation for that lifecycle method:

> If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Be sure that your component renders correctly for the original state (before the session check), as well as for the updated state (after the session check).

More about lifecycle methods and such [in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Alternately, if this component can't do anything useful without the session, you might move the session check to its parent component, and have the parent only render this child component when it has the session check results.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll take a look at `componentDidUpdate` and hopefully get this working.

Comment: I'm still struggling with how to execute the function before `render()` is hit. I thought about putting the code inside `componentDidMount` instead, but the login form shows before the session is checked and then is removed. I assume this is because the code is rendered before `componentDidMount` is called. Do you know where I might put this? Would I possibly need to set the state to show a blank page and then have `componentDidMount` set the correct states (does that make sense?). Thanks if you can help.

Comment: @Matt - You can't wait for an asynchronous process to complete before `render` is called. Instead, you do one of two things: 1. Have the component handle rendering itself correctly before the process is complete, with appropriate state for the fact it doesn't know the result yet (and then of course, it will re-render when its state changes because the process completes). 2. Have the *parent* component do the asynchronous check, and then only render this component when the check is complete.

Comment: I think that makes sense now, I'll have to handle it with `componentDidMount` to re-render the correct data. It may actually be easier to add the function to `index.js` and then render `<App />` after the checks. Am I on the right tracks? Thank you.

Comment: @Matt - Yes (sorry, I pointed you at the wrong method originally but you're right it's `componentDidUpdate`, have updated the answer now). Either of those (using `componentDidUpdate` or waiting until you have the session before having your app render the component) is good. Probably the latter unless your component can do something useful while the check is outstanding.

Answer (score 15):

**Functional Component:** In my case I wanted my code to run before component renders on the screen. `useLayoutEffect` is a hook provided by React for this exact purpose.

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
...
const App = () => {
   
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        //check local token or something

    }, []);
}
```

Read More: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: "Prefer the standard useEffect when possible to avoid blocking visual updates."

Comment: I agree @KostasMinaidis

Answer (score 2):

***useLayoutEffect* is NOT** correct way to execute code **before render**. Quote from [react.dev](https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect)

> useLayoutEffect is a version of useEffect that fires before the
> browser **repaints** the screen.

*repaints* does not mean that it'll trigger before the first render.

In Class components, ***componentWillMount*** will be executed before the render. The complete match of *componentWillMount* is **not** completely **exist** in functional components.

Possible solution is, put a boolean flag, make it true in *useEffect* (with empty dependency array), if it's false, that means it's before render.

```
export default function App() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)

  if (!isMounted.current){
   // your code here, executes before render
   }

  useEffect(() =>{
  // Initial render has been completed
  // make the flag true
    isMounted.current = true
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, you won't re-render the component (since no *setState()* triggers exist).

Comment: This approach looks promising. Thanks!