# how to output value from async method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I want to create a async method that returns an image path like this:

```
const renderMasterThumb = async (masterAssetId) => {
    const masterAsset = await getAssetByIdAsync(masterAssetId);
    const path = masterAsset.path;
    return path;
  };
```

then I call the method like this:

```
<img
    src={`images/${(async () => {
    await getAssetByIdAsync(collection.masterAssetId);
    })()}`}
    alt="master thumb"
/>
```

However instead of the image path I get a Promise object:

```
<img src="images/[object Promise]" alt="master thumb">
```

Does someone know how I can output the value (eg 'bart.jpg') from calling an async method?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Not just a duplicate of [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), as what needs doing here is completely restructuring the component. *(That said, there may well be a React-specific duplicate we can point to...)*

Comment: `async` infront of a function simply means: this function returns an promise. so you need to handle it like an promise

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741828/need-to-execute-function-before-render-in-reactjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your anonymous `async` function in your JSX still returns a promise, just like the one you're calling. You need to fundamentally restructure your React components. Either:

1. The component where this is being done has to be able to render when it doesn't have the result from `getAssetByIdAsync` yet (perhaps some "loading" placeholder), or
2. That component shouldn't be rendered at all until that result is available, which means doing the call to `getAssetByIdAsync` in the parent component instead of this one.

You need to do that in order to allow time for the asynchronous operation to complete. Within whatever component is doing it, you would use `.then` and `.catch` on the call to `getAssetByIdAsync` in order to handle the fulfillment or rejection of the promise it returns.

Comment: Crowler, thanks man, your suggestion helped me find the solution. I passed the renderMasterThumb method as prop to a child component. Then in the child component I render the renderMasterThumb method in the useEffect hook and set the path to a useState hook. This works!