# How can I run an async task before react app starts

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm looking for a handle that would allow me to run async code in the RN runtime **before** my React Native app executes.

I tried something like this

```
// index.js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

asyncTask.then(() => {
  AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
});
```

but the code crashes with

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered
> callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the
> error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Isn't there a provided way to run async tasks before the app starts ?

In my case I need this to do required updates on `AsyncStorage`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to Execute Function before render() in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741828/need-to-execute-function-before-render-in-reactjs)